# Slicing Mutliindex data with Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, indexing, slice

I have imported a csv as a multi-indexed Dataframe. Here's a mockup of the data:

`df = pd.read_csv("coursedata2.csv", index_col=[0,2])`

`print (df)`

```
                                  COURSE
```

`ID    Course List

12345 Interior Environments           DESN10000
      Rendering & Present Skills      DESN20065
      Lighting                        DESN20025
22345 Drawing Techniques              DESN10016
      Colour Theory                   DESN14049
      Finishes & Sustainable Issues   DESN12758
      Lighting                        DESN20025
32345 Window Treatments&Soft Furnish  DESN27370
42345 Introduction to CADD            INFO16859
      Principles of Drafting          DESN10065
      Drawing Techniques              DESN10016
      The Fundamentals of Design      DESN15436
      Colour Theory                   DESN14049
      Interior Environments           DESN10000
      Drafting                        DESN10123
      Textiles and Applications       DESN10199
      Finishes & Sustainable Issues   DESN12758`

```
[17 rows x 1 columns]
```

I can easily slice it by label using .xs -- eg:

`selected = df.xs (12345, level='ID')
 print selected`

```
                        COURSE
Course List                          
Interior Environments       DESN10000
Rendering & Present Skills  DESN20065
Lighting                    DESN20025

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

>

But what I want to do is step through the dataframe and perform an operation on each block of courses, by ID. The ID values in the real data are fairly random integers, sorted in ascending order.

df.index shows:

`df.index
MultiIndex(levels=[[12345, 22345, 32345, 42345], [u'Colour Theory', u'Colour Theory ', u'Drafting', u'Drawing Techniques', u'Finishes & Sustainable Issues', u'Interior Environments', u'Introduction to CADD', u'Lighting', u'Principles of Drafting', u'Rendering & Present Skills', u'Textiles and Applications', u'The Fundamentals of Design', u'Window Treatments&Soft Furnish']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [5, 9, 7, 3, 1, 4, 7, 12, 6, 8, 3, 11, 0, 5, 2, 10, 4]],
           names=[u'ID', u'Course List'])`

It seems to me that I should be able to use the first index labels to increment through the Dataframe. Ie. Get all the courses for label 0 then 1 then 2 then 3,... but it looks like .xs will not slice by label.

Am I missing something?

Comment: try ``df.groupby(level='ID').apply(func)`, see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-with-multiindex

Answer (score 0):

So there may be more efficient ways to do this, depending on what you're trying to do to the data. However, there are two approaches which immediately come to mind:

```
for id_label in df.index.levels[0]:
    some_func(df.xs(id_label, level='ID'))
```

and

```
for id_label in df.index.levels[0]:
    df.xs(id_label, level='ID').apply(some_func, axis=1)
```

depending on whether you want to operate on the group as a whole or on each row with in it.

Comment: I want to compare the slice to a static list of courses, so I think the first approach looks very promising. Many thanks.